# Stored-Procedure to Delete row where this condition True:

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I need Stored-Procedure That **AUTOMATICALLY** Deletes everytime row, where in table `paym` both columns `table1` and `table2` are not empty.

Example in tables below:
table: `paym`

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |  Value      |    Value  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Condition is True: After Deleted row:

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**My attemp is:** (Not working)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRow
        BEGIN
              DELETE
        FROM
            paym WHERE table1 and table2 IS NOT NULL ;
            END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is right here, but the syntax is wrong.

After every field on WHERE clause you must specify a condition, just like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRow
         BEGIN
               DELETE
         FROM
             paym WHERE table1 IS NOT NULL AND table2 IS NOT NULL ;
             END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `COALESCE`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRow
BEGIN
DELETE FROM paym WHERE COALESCE(table1,table2) IS NOT NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

the code should read table is not null and table 2 is not null, as you need to have a condition after an and statement.